# How to clear browser cookies in .net maui for iOS

Tags: ios, cookies, maui

To open a browser in .net maui we are using:

```
await Browser.Default.OpenAsync(_viewModel.OMNIANotificationParamter.NotificationURL, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
```

We want to clear cookies before it, and for android we use:

```
CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookies(null);
CookieManager.Instance.Flush();
```

But the previous code is not recognized for iOS.

What can we use for iOS?

We have tried to use the following, but we did not succeeded in compilation:

```
var storage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
var cookies = storage.Cookies;

foreach (var cookie in cookies) 
{
    storage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: the user is going to be very unhappy with your app if it clears all of their cookies.  Which is why the OS doesn't allow you to do that

Comment: You cannot do this